# Can Jackson/Gson give me all known deserializable field names?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jackson2

If I have a POJO:

```
public class Item {

  @JsonProperty("itemName")
  public String name;
  private int quantity;

  @JsonGetter("quantity") //call it "quantity" when serializing
  public int getQuantity() {...}

  @JsonSetter("number") //call it "number" when deserializing
  public void setQuantity() {...}
}
```

or the same with Gson annotations:

```
public class Item {

  @SerializedName("itemName")
  public String name;

  @SerializedName("number")
  private int quantity;

  ...
}
```

Is there a way to use Jackson/Gson to get all field names that it would know how to **deserialize** (`itemName` and `number` in this case)?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. I am not able to follow what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Jackson:

```
public static List<String> getDeserializationProperties(Class<?> beanType)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(beanType);
    BeanDescription desc = mapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(type);
    return desc.findProperties().stream()
            .filter(def -> def.couldDeserialize())
            .map(def -> def.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Calling:

```
System.out.println(getDeserializationProperties(Item.class));
```

Output:

```
[itemName, number]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Gson, the closest thing could be serializing an instantiated-only object and then converting it to a JSON tree in order to extract the JSON object properties:

```java
final class Item {

    @SerializedName("itemName")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("number")
    int quantity;

}
```

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls() // This is necessary: Gson excludes null values by default, otherwise primitive values only
        .create();
final List<String> names = gson.toJsonTree(new Item())
        .getAsJsonObject()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(toList());
System.out.println(names);
```

The output:

> [itemName, number]

Comment: Ok, I removed the duplicate. Sorry for my error. And thanks again for the help! I'll ask on Meta.